# FMX TCameraComponent with IFMXCameraService bug

Tags: android, delphi, camera, firemonkey

In the app I need to scan a Barcode, then access the camera to take photos followed by further Barcode scanning.

Therefore, I use both the TCameraComponent and IFMXCameraService interface.

The problem occurs once I start the TCameraComponent (for scanning a Barcode code), then deactivate it and take a photo... when i go back to TCameraComponent i get error: **raised exception class EJNIException with message 'java.lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)'**.

An important clarification: if you first get a photo, and then open the barcode scanner, there is no error. The error appears if you open the barcode scanner at least once, close it, take a photo, and open the scanner again.

Start scanner:

```
    if ( Length( AGrantResults ) = 1 ) and ( AGrantResults[ 0 ] = TPermissionStatus.Granted ) then
     begin
      SetCaptureSetting();
      FBuffer.Clear( TAlphaColors.White );
      FActive := True;
      LabelFPS.Text := 'Start capturing...';
      FCamera.Active := True;
      StartStopWatch();
      lblScanning.Text := 'Scan On';
      FaLblScanning.Enabled := True;
     end else
      Showmessage( '' );
```

Stop scanner:

```
 lblScanning.Text := 'Scan Off';
 FaLblScanning.Enabled := False;
 FActive := False;
 DisplaySlowWarning(False);
 FCamera.Active := False; 
 LabelFPS.Text := '';
```

Take photo:

```
var
 Params: TParamsPhotoQuery;
 Service: IFMXCameraService;
begin
 if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService( IFMXCameraService, Service ) then
  begin
   Params.Editable := False;
   Params.NeedSaveToAlbum    := False;
   Params.RequiredResolution := TSize.Create( 1080, 1920 );
   Params.OnDidFinishTaking  := DoDidFinish;
   Service.TakePhoto( btnTakePhoto, Params );
  end else
   ShowMessage('This device does not support the camera service');
```

I tried making Service global, and using Service := nil after taking photo, did not help.

Comment: What does SetCaptureSetting() do, and what is the "barcode scanner" you're referring to?

Comment: SetCaptureSetting () function set FCamera.CaptureSetting := CaptureSettings[ CaptureSettingsIndex ]; CaptureSettings: TArray<TVideoCaptureSetting>; This is the settings array obtained earlier. I use:github.com/Spelt/ZXing.Delphi But I don't think the problem is with the scanner. I tried to disable it completely, and here a similar problem with another scanner is described, but no solution has been found delphi-developers-archive.blogspot.com/2016/06/hi-guys.html

Comment: Have you tried this: https://delphiworlds.com/2020/11/native-camera-ios-android/

Answer (score 0):

Try add the property before active the camera

`CameraComponent.Quality := FMX.Media.TVideoCaptureQuality.MediumQuality;`

Comment: Did this end up working for the original poster?